# Different responses of BASH cURL and PHP cURL with identical request headers

Tags: php, bash, curl

This is a kind of very interesting problem.

I'm writing an API for a micro web radio player. To get the current track I'm parsing the cast servers frontend.

In the example of http://deepmix.ru, which is  a SHOUTcast 1.x server, I'd able to parse the URI http://85.21.79.31:7128/played.html.

When I request the URI in FireFox I get the webpage displaying the list of played tracks. If I request that URI with cURL from BASH of my server hosting my API I get a 404 of that server.

```sh
$ curl -v -G http://85.21.79.31:7128/played.html
*   Trying 85.21.79.31...
* Connected to 85.21.79.31 (85.21.79.31) port 7128 (#0)
> GET /played.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: 85.21.79.31:7128
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
ICY 404 Resource Not Found
icy-notice1:<BR>SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.8<BR>
icy-notice2:The resource requested was not found<BR>

* Connection #0 to host 85.21.79.31 left intact
```

I assumed a proper user agent may help and add `Mozilla` to receive the webpage. So that worked.

```sh
$ curl -v -A "Mozilla" -G http://85.21.79.31:7128/played.html
*   Trying 85.21.79.31...
* Connected to 85.21.79.31 (85.21.79.31) port 7128 (#0)
> GET /played.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: 85.21.79.31:7128
> User-Agent: Mozilla
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< content-type:text/html
< 
<HTML>[...]<title>SHOUTcast Administrator</title>[...]</HEAD><BODY topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 bgcolor=#000000 text=#EEEEEE link=#001155 vlink=#001155 alink=#FF0000><font class=default><table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><tr><td height=50><font class=logoText>&nbsp;SHOUTcast Song History</font></td></tr><tr><td height=14 align=right><font class=ltv><a id=ltv href="http://www.shoutcast.com/">SHOUTcast Server Version 1.9.8/Linux</a>[...]</body></html>
```

According to my discoveries I transferred the request into my PHP cURL implementation.

```php
$curlHandler = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array(
    $curlHandler,
    [
        CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT     => true,
        CURLOPT_URL             => 'http://85.21.79.31:7128/played.html',
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => 'Mozilla',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
        CURLOPT_NOBODY          => true
    ]
);
$response = curl_exec( $curlHandler );
$info     = curl_getinfo( $curlHandler );
curl_close( $curlHandler );
var_dump( $info );
var_dump( $response );
```

But I got the 404 response.

```
array(31) {
  ["request_header"]=>
  string(87) "GET /played.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 85.21.79.31:7128
User-Agent: Mozilla
Accept: */*

"
}
```

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://85.21.79.31:7128/played.html): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! ICY 404 Resource Not Found
 in /vagrant/src/Readers/CurrentTrackReader.php on line 50
```

While comparing the request headers there's no differences. So I assume there's differences between BASH's and PHP's cURL implementations I cannot see.

So what happens here?

**Update (2019-07-31)**

Additonal runtime environment information

OS

```
Linux hostname 4.19.0-0.bpo.5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-4~bpo9+1 (2019-06-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

PHP

```
PHP Version 7.3.7-2+0~20190725.42+debian9~1.gbp848ca5
```

**Update (2019-07-31)**

Additional information about cURL

BASH

```sh
$ curl --version
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

phpinfo()

```
cURL support     | enabled
cURL Information | 7.52.1
Age              | 3

Features

AsynchDNS        | Yes
CharConv         | No
Debug            | No
GSS-Negotiate    | No
IDN              | Yes
IPv6             | Yes
krb4             | No
Largefile        | Yes
libz             | Yes
NTLM             | Yes
NTLMWB           | Yes
SPNEGO           | Yes
SSL              | Yes
SSPI             | No
TLS-SRP          | Yes
HTTP2            | Yes
GSSAPI           | Yes
KERBEROS5        | Yes
UNIX_SOCKETS     | Yes
PSL              | Yes
HTTPS_PROXY      | Yes
Protocols        | dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host             | x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
SSL Version      | OpenSSL/1.0.2s
ZLib Version     | 1.2.8
libSSH Version   | libssh2/1.7.0


Directive   | Local Value | Master Value
curl.cainfo | no value    | no value
```

Comment: Try a different user agent like `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0` post the output.

Comment: The response is the same 404. I already tried that. But generally there's no assumption by the further BASH tests this would lead to a different response. To clarify my question I added information about the runtime environment.

Comment: I fixed the version of the PHP version while I first posted the CLI-version which is different from the FAST-CGI module version.

Comment: Your code works fine for me when running on docker container with `php:7.3.7-fpm`: `["http_code"]=> int(200)`

Comment: I think this is a good question, but I'd rephrase the title (which is extremely broad) to fit your actual question more specifically.

Comment: @moshe `phpinfo()` shows cURL is of version `7.52.1`. If you can provide the version in your docker container this may help.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I tried to find a short question to specify my problem. Any suggestions from you?

Comment: "PHP curl request gets 404 response, but Bash curl request with identical header gets 200"? Not the best title on the planet, though ;)

Comment: @BenjaminW. I changed the question and I additionally provided infos of the underlying cURL's OS and PHP versions.

Comment: `cURL Information => 7.64.0` @codekandis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very big fault of myself.

First I left that `CURLOPT_NOBODY => true` in the code (see the question) which leads to an empty response.

Second I left `file_get_contents( $uri )` in my code which leads to the warning posted in the question.

In conclusion while removing these both cURL works as expected.